# Align Bootstrap 4 custom form(checkbox)

Tags: html, css, checkbox, bootstrap-4, bootswatch

With Bootstrap 4 and bootswatch, I'd like to place the four Django form fileds, `since`(`col-sm-2`/textinput), `until`(`col-sm-2`/textinput), `currently_employed`(`col-sm-7`/custom checkbox) and form close button(`col-sm-1`/`a` tag) in-row.

But it rendered wrong like this on the custom checkbox(checkbox is in wrong place):

[image]

The codes for above are:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.0.0-beta.3/solar/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Jpv9vxZao0dlyvegpeTxSgc5cczNCOpcV5ihm8RQbrMo263QmC3Sf5HIMBfr+nqx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-sm-1 float-right">
    <!-- Empty Career: Close form button -->
    <a class="btn btn-default float-right close-career">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 float-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="career-__prefix__-since" class="form-control" placeholder="0000.0" id="id_career-__prefix__-since" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 float-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="career-__prefix__-until" class="form-control" placeholder="0000.0" id="id_career-__prefix__-until" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="career-__prefix__-currently_employed" class="custom-control-input form-control float-left" id="id_career-__prefix__-currently_employed" />
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="id_career-__prefix__-currently_employed">
                Currently employed
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

`since` and `until` are `float-left`, and close button is `float-right`.

To look that correct, I added the class `float-left` to `currently_employed`, it look good but not clickable:

[image]

Changed code for that is:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.0.0-beta.3/solar/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Jpv9vxZao0dlyvegpeTxSgc5cczNCOpcV5ihm8RQbrMo263QmC3Sf5HIMBfr+nqx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-sm-1 float-right">
    <!-- Empty Career: Close form button -->
    <a class="btn btn-default float-right close-career">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 float-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="career-__prefix__-since" class="form-control" placeholder="0000.0" id="id_career-__prefix__-since" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 float-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="career-__prefix__-until" class="form-control" placeholder="0000.0" id="id_career-__prefix__-until" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-7 float-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="career-__prefix__-currently_employed" class="custom-control-input form-control float-left" id="id_career-__prefix__-currently_employed" />
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="id_career-__prefix__-currently_employed">
                Currently employed
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How could I make it both clickable and look good?

Comment: Please post the **complete** HTML *output* snippet. (remove other code)

Comment: @WebDevBooster Edited. You mean without django templates right? I removed some white spaces.

Comment: No, I mean HTML **output**. Visit the page in a browser, view code and copy the HTML from there.

Comment: @WebDevBooster That is which is the part of the screenshot. Or whole html?

Comment: *complete* code snippet that includes all of the relevant HTML that allows to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it exactly. I think the issue is about the presence or absence of class `float-left` in `div` tag with `col-sm-7` which is parent of checkbox input.. I import [bootswatch's solar theme](https://bootswatch.com/4/solar/bootstrap.min.css) and use them, no custom css for that part.

Here is [the gist for whole HTML](https://gist.github.com/flavono123/07a401f4969dddeb372fe3dc24fac64d). Sorry again though you helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this you must first put the entire thing into a `.container` or `.container-fluid` and then put that into a `.row` and into that row all your columns. And make sure you **remove all your `float` classes** such as `float-right` etc.

Then you just add the class `order-sm-last` to the first column and that's it!

The `order-sm-last` will move/re-order that first column (with the close button) to the last for screens that small (`sm`) or bigger. And for the smallest screens, the position of the first column will remain unchanged.

Here's the working code snippet (click the "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>

<!-- Empty Career: Visible Fields -->
<div class="container-fluid mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1 text-right order-sm-last">
            <!-- Empty Career: Close form button -->
            <a class="btn btn-default close-career">
                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="career-__prefix__-since" class="form-control" placeholder="0000.0" id="id_career-__prefix__-since" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="career-__prefix__-until" class="form-control" placeholder="0000.0" id="id_career-__prefix__-until" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="career-__prefix__-currently_employed" class="custom-control-input form-control" id="id_career-__prefix__-currently_employed" />
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="id_career-__prefix__-currently_employed">
                        Currently employed
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Read the explanation I just added to my answer. Your `float` classes must be removed.

Comment: My question was unverifiable.. Thanks for a lot, not just for fixing my case but also teaching for asking right and preventing to abuse `float`. I'll read this answer again and again to understand.

Comment: Yes, normally, you want to avoid using any `float` with Bootstrap 4 because Bootstrap 4 is flexbox-based. Everything is much easier with flexbox.

Comment: Here's a link to understand how the order classes work: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes